# Why my ajax post does not replace the content?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this:

```
 <div id="miniShoppingCartContainer">
      @Html.Action("MiniShoppingCart", "ShoppingCart")
 </div>
```

where MiniShoppingCart action returns MiniShoppingCart.cshtml partial view with all the content.

In this partial view I added an ajax call for increasing the quantity of product cart:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("IncreaseProductQuantity", "ShoppingCart", new { shoppingCartItemId = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "miniShoppingCartContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    <li>
        <input type="submit" class="btn-up" />
    </li>
}
```

which calls a method:

```
public ActionResult IncreaseProductQuantity(int shoppingCartItemId)
    {
        //get shopping cart item
        var cart = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.ShoppingCartItems
            .Where(x => x.ShoppingCartType == ShoppingCartType.ShoppingCart).ToList();
        var sci = cart.Where(x => x.Id == shoppingCartItemId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (sci == null)
        {
            return RedirectToRoute("ShoppingCart");
        }

        //update the cart item
        _shoppingCartService.UpdateShoppingCartItem(_workContext.CurrentCustomer,
                               sci.Id, sci.Quantity + 1, true);


        return MiniShoppingCart();
    }
```

Please note that at the end of the method I **call the MiniShoppingCart** ActionResult which prepares the cart and return the PartialView (as you see at the beginning of the post).

Well, the update of a product is happening fine but the content is not refreshed (or replaced)...

Can you please indicate where I am wrong?

**UPDATE**:

Doing an inspection with Chrome Dev. Tools I see an error when doing post:

```
    POST http://localhost/ShoppingCart/IncreaseProductQuantity?shoppingCartItemId=11 500 (Internal Server Error)
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
f.extend.ajaxjquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
ejquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:5
(anonymous function)jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:5
f.event.dispatchjquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.ijquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
2
```

It's strange to guess what is the problem from this log...Basically, If I make debug I can see that it does all the operations until `return PartialView(model);` of `MiniShoppingCart()` method...

Comment: Do you have the unobtrusive ajax js file included `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` in your View/Layout?

Comment: Yes, I have this included: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: You should check in the browser's development console (IE/Chrome F12) or in FireBug what is the `IncreaseProductQuantity` is returning. Maybe you will see hint what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Issue found:

```
>The partial view 'IncreaseProductQuantity' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.
```

So basically, doing `return MiniShoppingCart();` from `IncreaseProductQuantity` method doesn't automatically return the MiniShoppingCart partial view but will still try to return `IncreaseProductQuantity` partial view which of course does not exists.

Consequently, I have done it like:

```
var model = PrepareMiniShoppingCartModel();
return PartialView("MiniShoppingCart", model);
```